# Change color of input labels with jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to change the class of my form input labels when a specific field fails to validate. I want to add the 'error' class to the spans directly above any invalid form elements.

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<span class="label">What kind service do you need?</span><br />
<div style="float: left; width: 220px; margin: 5px 21px 0 0;"><input type="checkbox" name="serviceType"><label>Option 1</label></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 220px; margin: 5px 21px 0 0;"><input type="checkbox" name="serviceType"><label>Option 2</label></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 220px; margin: 5px 21px 0 0;"><input type="checkbox" name="serviceType"><label>Option 3</label></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 220px; margin: 5px 0 0 0;"><input type="checkbox" name="serviceType"><label>Option 4</label></div>
<div id="clear"></div>

<span class="label">When do you need service?</span><br />
<div id="inputSmall"><input type="text" class="small" name="serviceDate" /></div>

<span class="label">How often?</span><br />
<div id="inputSmall"><select class="small" name="recurringBasis">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="single">One time</option>
<option value="weekly">One a week</option>
</select></div>
```

And this is my JS:

```
$("#quote").validate({
  rules: {
    serviceDate: "required",
    recurringBasis: "required",
    serviceType: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 1            
    }
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).prev('span').addClass("error");
  },
  unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).prev('span').removeClass("error");
  }
});
```

I've seen suggestions to use the highlight/unhighlight approach, but that doesn't appear to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your selector `$(element).prev('span')` is wrong

Try

```
$(element).parent().prev().prev('span')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Xf8AM/)

Comment: I tried using `$(element).parent().prev('span').addClass("error");` and that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: @Jeremy it was not working because the `prev()` element was `<br />

Comment: That worked great. However, I have a couple checkboxes in the form that aren't validating with this approach. I believe it's because they have a different number of elements between themselves and the label. Please seem my update.

Comment: @Jeremy can you modify the fiddle with the case and post a link

Comment: Ok, so I played around with it in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DNEwC/) and it works fine. I think the problem is caused with a custom checkbox script that I'm running that adds a bunch of HTML to the checkboxes after the fact for style purposes. Would there be any way of doing this that doesn't require us to know the exact .prev() position of the span?

Comment: I ended up going with this, and it worked great `$(element).parent().parent().prev().prev('span').addClass("error");`. Thanks for the help!